# Polars DataFrames Python do replacement by using mask which itself is another Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

How to change variables (or recreate) dataframe, with another boolean mask Polars DataFrame?
So not just single column vectors (Series), but both a DataFrame.

So set the following to 1000, where amount > 270, value at the bottom would become 1000

Input:

```
            apples[0].amount  apples[1].amount...  apples[3].amount  apples[4].amount
    0                  NaN       321.68012  ...             NaN             NaN
    1                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    2                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    3                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    4                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    ...                ...             ...  ...             ...             ...
    440582        79.57273             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440583             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440584             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440585             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440586             NaN             NaN  ...       299.91544             NaN


    [440587 rows x 5 columns]
```

Expected Output:

```
            apples[0].amount  apples[1].amount...  apples[3].amount  apples[4].amount
    0                  NaN       1000.00000 ...             NaN             NaN
    1                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    2                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    3                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    4                  NaN             NaN  ...             NaN       259.70487
    ...                ...             ...  ...             ...             ...
    440582        79.57273             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440583             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440584             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440585             NaN             NaN  ...             NaN             NaN
    440586             NaN             NaN  ...       1000.00000            NaN


    [440587 rows x 5 columns]
```

**Another example**:
cum_sum_volume_apples input:

```
        apples[0].amount  apples[1].amount  ...  apples[3].amount  apples[4].amount
0            321.66164      1322.18012  ...      1581.98712      1683.34388
1            321.66164       574.39164  ...       849.15207      1260.20487
2            321.66164       574.39164  ...       849.15207      1260.20487
3            321.66164       574.39164  ...       849.15207      1260.20487
4            321.66164       574.39164  ...       849.15207      1260.20487
...                ...             ...  ...             ...             ...
440582      1080.07273      1089.38273  ...      3248.32543      3266.94847
440583         9.06278        26.69990  ...      1107.99783      1117.30783
440584       346.34516       363.98228  ...      1445.28021      1454.59021
440585       346.34516       363.98228  ...       882.09418       891.40418
440586       426.89556       773.24072  ...      1300.41544      1308.98974

[440587 rows x 5 columns]
```

at_or_above_threshold_mask ~1000

```
        apples[0].amount  apples[1].amount  ...  apples[3].amount  apples[4].amount
0                False            True  ...           False           False
1                False           False  ...           False            True
2                False           False  ...           False            True
3                False           False  ...           False            True
4                False           False  ...           False            True
...                ...             ...  ...             ...             ...
440582            True           False  ...           False           False
440583           False           False  ...           False           False
440584           False           False  ...           False           False
440585           False           False  ...           False           False
440586           False           False  ...            True           False

[440587 rows x 5 columns]
```

How to filter on just the true values, with the at_threshold_mask, on another dataframe with the same x/y length? (a sample could include a mask on the already existing cum_sum_volume_apples above)

```
cum_sum_all = pl.cum_sum_horizontal("*")
at_or_above_threshold_boolean_cum_sum = (
        (cum_sum_volume_apples >= volume_threshold).select(cum_sum_all).unnest("cum_sum")
    )
at_or_above_threshold_mask = at_or_above_threshold_boolean_cum_sum >= 1
at_threshold_mask = at_or_above_threshold_boolean_cum_sum == 1
```

Comment: Your two tables look the same I don't see one that is "another boolean mask Polars DataFrame"

Comment: apples[1] `321.68012` should also change, right? i.e. you simply want to replace all values `> 270` with `1000.` in your dataframe?

Comment: @jqurious you are right! I updated the question

Comment: they should be python floats

Comment: Okay, so the "mask" is from the DataFrame itself and **not** another one. Also, if you can provide a runnable code example e.g. `df = pl.DataFrame(...)` - it makes it much easier for people to answer.

Comment: @jqurious I added another example which should illustrate my problem better

Comment: Are you asking for an equivalent of `df[df_mask]` from pandas? I don't think Polars has any shorthand syntax for that, you could manually `df.select(pl.when(cond).then(col) for cond, col in zip(df_mask, df.columns))`

Comment: @jqurious, I think you're right on this, thanks a lot for you suggestions

Comment: @jqurious but there is not something similar as the df[df_mask] in polars?

Comment: There is no shorthand syntax for such an operation as far as I am aware.

Comment: @jqurious maybe contact polars team about this, df[df_mask] appears like quite basic syntax which is missing? but maybe semantically not so nice

Comment: *"I don't want DataFrames to be seen as matrices."* - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14078#issuecomment-1915401402 - There also appears to be an old request for this exact feature: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5782

Comment: @jqurious a so basically the recommended usage is to do to_numpy, I always thought pandas dataframes used numpys behind the screens

Answer (score 2):

In this case the "mask" is from the frame itself, in which case you can use [`pl.when().then()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when)

We can use [`pl.all()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.all.html) to refer to all columns at once.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.all() > 270)
     .then(1000.0)         # replace with 1000.0
     .otherwise(pl.all())  # otherwise keep the existing value
     .name.keep()
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 4)
┌──────────┬────────┬────────┬───────────┐
│ A        ┆ B      ┆ C      ┆ D         │
│ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64    ┆ f64    ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════════╡
│ null     ┆ 1000.0 ┆ null   ┆ null      │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ 259.70487 │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ 259.70487 │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ 259.70487 │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ 259.70487 │
│ 79.57273 ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ null      │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ null      │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ null      │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ null   ┆ null      │
│ null     ┆ null   ┆ 1000.0 ┆ null      │
└──────────┴────────┴────────┴───────────┘
```

Without [`name.keep()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.keep.html#polars.Expr.name.keep) we get:

```py
ComputeError: the name: 'literal' passed to `LazyFrame.with_columns` is duplicate
```

This is because multiple columns for `1000.0` named [`literal`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html#polars.lit) are created.

```py
>>> pl.select(1000.0) # same as pl.select(pl.lit(1000.0))
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ literal │
│ ---     │
│ f64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 1000.0  │
└─────────┘
```

`.name.keep()` will keep the original column names (from `pl.all()` in this example).

Comment: I added another example, let me know what you think

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer @jquirous provided, you can also use the `.clip` method
to replace values greater or below some set of thresholds.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 20, 10],
    'c': [3, 5, 3, 18, 20]
})

print(
    df,
    # shape: (5, 3)
    # ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
    # │ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
    # │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
    # │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
    # ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
    # │ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   │
    # │ 5   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
    # │ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
    # │ 15  ┆ 20  ┆ 18  │
    # │ 20  ┆ 10  ┆ 20  │
    # └─────┴─────┴─────┘

    df.select(pl.all().clip(upper_bound=15)),
    # shape: (5, 3)
    # ┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
    # │ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
    # │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
    # │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
    # ╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
    # │ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   │
    # │ 5   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
    # │ 10  ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
    # │ 15  ┆ 15  ┆ 15  │
    # │ 15  ┆ 10  ┆ 15  │
    # └─────┴─────┴─────┘

    sep='\n\n'
)
```